# Loading spinner always present on Android app feed

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

No matter how I scroll in the feed, the spinner from the `SwipeRefreshLayout` is always present. Also it jumps between different states, like animating between visible and not. This happens regardless of the scroll direction or where in the list I am. If I stand completely in the list it disappear, but comes when I start scrolling.

I have version 1.0.69 of the app and Android 5.1.1.

Comment: What device and version of Android are you using?

Comment: I just had the same thing happening in the feed view on. App v. 1.0.77, Android 5.1.1 custom ROM on Sony Z2. I can reproduce this when scrolling fast and letting to, when it attempts to load new content it will flash from small to big (like it would animate when you trigger a refresh). Eventually the loading spinner will stay.

Comment: Probably related: [Blank circle appears like loading indicator on every move of scroll view](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262197/)

Comment: @Kasra if it's of any help, this [was reported again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286723/refresh-keeps-occuring), this time will full details.