# Blank circle appears like loading indicator on every move of scroll view

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

I'm using Android 5.1. There is a bug in the Feed view with the loading indicator. The normal loading indicator still exists. Some more information: because my feed view is now bigger, I discovered the bug only in the last half of the page. The bug appears to be the load circle to load old data from the timeline. Normally it just works, but at the end of the timeline, it goes crazy.

> [image: blank circle on feed]

Comment: Probably related: [Loading spinner always present on Android app feed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261387/loading-spinner-always-present)